# tf.VERSION is always 1.6.0 even though I installed the latest version

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Please help me to solve the problem  - I use Google's Colaboratory to run tensor_hub example Text classification with TF-Hub, it needs the version later than 1.7.0, but the version I installed is 1.8.0.

```py
# Install the latest Tensorflow version.
!pip install --quiet "tensorflow>=1.7"
# Install TF-Hub.
!pip install tensorflow-hub

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import seaborn as sns



RuntimeErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-20-48e1bdaa8642> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 import tensorflow_hub as hub
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import os

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py in <module>()
     63 
     64 # Comment/uncomment to skip checking the TensorFlow version.
---> 65 _check_tensorflow_version(tf.VERSION)
     66 
     67 # Used by doc generation script.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py in
_check_tensorflow_version(version)
     60       "TensorFlow Hub depends on 'tf-nightly' build after %s or "
     61       "'tensorflow~=%s'. Found tf.VERSION = %s" % (
---> 62           _NIGHTLY_VERSION, _MAIN_VERSION, version))
     63 
     64 # Comment/uncomment to skip checking the TensorFlow version.

RuntimeError: TensorFlow Hub depends on 'tf-nightly' build after 20180308 or 'tensorflow~=1.7'. Found tf.VERSION = 1.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to restart the runtime.

`menu > Runtime > Restart runtime...`

Answer (score 2):

Good news: TF 1.7 is now available by default. :)

The underlying problem you were hitting is just that python caches loaded modules in `sys.modules` -- re-importing a module doesn't pick up the new version until you restart the process, as Korakot noted.